# Looking to calculate break even price (minus fees) on an individual level without brute forcing

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to calculate the break-even price on an individual product given a percent of the price I sold it for and the price I bought it for. For example: I buy an item for $200 and the fees on the sale of the item are 13% of the final sale price. I want the answer to be $230.

$230 (sale price) * .13 (percent fee) = $29.90 (fee in dollars) (round up to $30)

$230 (sale price) - $200 (item cost) - $30 (fee) = $0 (break even)

So if I buy an item at $200 I need to sell it at $230 just to break even.

This seems like an easy problem but I haven't been able to figure out a way that isn't brute force because the fee changes with every sold price so there doesn't seem like a way to know the fee in advance. I've been just guessing and plugging in the numbers but there has got to be another way so I can write up a simple script.

I also don't care about cents, I'm going to round everything up.

**I am looking for a non-brute algorithm.** The only thing I can come up with is brute forcing it and I'm sure there is a better algorithm that exists. Looking at various inputs and outputs I don't see a pattern.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this is elementary maths rather than a conceptual programming problem.

Comment: I am sorry if this is "basic math" but I did look at the rules to see if it was allowed here. programmers.stackexchange.com/tour says I can ask about "algorithms and data structures" and I am looking for an algorithm. I know the math but I am having trouble coming up with a non-brute force algorithm given arbitrary inputs.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you elaborate? Are you just looking for the equation saleprice=price*(1+percent fee)? Or are you trying to calculate the percent fee?

Comment: Sounds like it though I would name it `breakEvenPrice` rather than `saleprice`.

Comment: @Guest I would like two inputs: item cost, percent fee. Output would be price I would have to sell it for to break even ($0 profit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you take off the 13%, you have 87% remaining.  You multiply by 0.87 to get your revenue:

```
$230 * 0.87 == $200.10
```

From this point, it's basic algebra to show if you know the $200 you *divide* by 0.87 to get $230.  So, your formula is:

```
original price / (1 - fees)
$200 / (1 - 0.13) = $229.89
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something obvious - I was approaching the problem backwards.